# How to setup default windows at startup?

Tags: window, init-file, session

Every time I open up Emacs I tend to set up 3 windows by doing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> (`split-window-right`) and then <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (`split-window-below`). After that I have to switch to each window to open the files I want to edit.

How can I set this to be done automatically?

Is there a way to have Emacs recover the same screen organization (windows and files) from last use?

Answer (score 14):

Since Emacs 24.4, you can use [desktop-save-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). It's been part of Emacs for ages, but the window layout is only saved and restored since version 24.4.

Just add this line in your init file:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: This will restore files from the previous session, but it will not restore the window layout.

Comment: Nope, I've tested it.

_Emacs Manual_: Once you save the Emacs desktop — the buffers, their file names, major modes, *buffer* *positions*, and so on — then subsequent Emacs sessions reload the saved desktop.

Comment: "Buffer position" refers to the position of *point* (the cursor) in a given buffer. Yes, this will be restored with `desktop-save-mode`. Window layout refers to how many windows are currently displayed and how they are positioned. `desktop-save-mode` does not preserve this layout.

Comment: Note that I am not criticizing your answer. I am simply pointing out that using `desktop-save-mode` does not address *all* of the aspects that the OP is interested in.

Comment: Yes, "window layout" and "buffer position" are different things, you are correct.

But my window layout was restored. It looks like saving of window layout was added in emacs-snapshot.

Comment: I see. That's good news! I'll rephrase my comment, then: `desktop-save-mode` *might* not restore the window layout :)

Comment: `desktop-save-mode` does restore the window layout IF you have an emacs with version 24.4 or higher, like the OP says

Comment: @pors, it seems not the case if you are using Emacs (24.4 or higher) in terminal mode. No window configuration is saved/restored.

Comment: It restores *frame* layout, not *window* layout. Frame is what normal people call window.

Answer (score 8):

write a function close to that one in your init file, you will probably have to modify it a little bit to fit your needs:

```
;; layout definition
(defun my-startup-layout ()
 (interactive)
 (delete-other-windows)
 (split-window-horizontally) ;; -> |
 (next-multiframe-window)
 (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init.el")
 (split-window-vertically) ;;  -> --
 (next-multiframe-window)
 (find-file "~/.emacs.d/init_settings.el")
 (next-multiframe-window)
 (dired "~")
)

;; execute the layout
(my-startup-layout )
```

> is there a way to have Emacs recover the same screen organization (windows and files) from last use?

You should have a look at the [layout](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LayoutRestore) package

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`workgroups2`](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2) to manage your desktop. From the README on GitHub:

> Workgroups is a session manager for Emacs.
>
> - It saves all your opened buffers, their location and sizes on disk to restore later
> - You can create several workspaces
>
> You can also restore such buffers as: org-agenda, shell, magit-status, help.

If you have the [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) repository enabled, you can install this package via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `workgroups2` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

The basic setup is:

```el
(require 'workgroups2)
(workgroups-mode 1) ; This should go at the end of your init file
```

When you restart Emacs for the first time after adding this code to your init file, `workgroups2` will automatically create a workgroup for you. You can verify that this was successful by checking the `*Messages*` buffer for the following information:

```
Workgroups Mode: on
Switched: First workgroup
Created: First workgroup  ( -<{ 0: First workgroup }>- )
```

From this point on, Emacs will save the current configuration of windows and files automatically on exit, and restore it the next time it starts.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using something modeled after [sanityinc's .emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-sessions.el).
It uses `desktop-save-mode`, and also is smart enough to use `frame-restore` on older versions emacs.
From the readme for `frame-restore` from `package-list-packages`:

> Save and restore parameters of Emacs frames.
>
> Just call `frame-restore' in your`init.el':
>
> (frame-restore-mode)
>
> Note that since r113242 the built-in Desktop Save mode will restore
>   frames. If you are using a Emacs snapshot build later than this
>   revision, you are
>   *strongly* advised to use Desktop Save mode instead:
>
> (desktop-save-mode)
>
> Frame Restore mode will display a bold warning if enabled in an Emacs
>   build whose Desktop Save mode can restore frames.