# desktop-save-mode fails to save window layout

Tags: window, frames, window-splitting, desktop, session

I use `Emacs 24.5.1` on OS X in terminal mode.

I intend to use `desktop-save-mode` to save and restore window layout (i.e. positions of buffer windows) upon exiting and starting `Emacs`.

From [this answer and its comments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/857/10491), people suggest that recent versions of `Emacs` does save and restore window layout when `desktop-save-mode` is enabled. However, when I exit `Emacs` with two side-by-side windows each containing a file buffer, only the last active buffer (the one where the cursor last rested at) is restored upon restarting `Emacs`.

My relevant configurations are:

```
(setq desktop-auto-save-timeout nil
      desktop-save 'ask-if-new
      desktop-dirname "./"
      desktop-path (list desktop-dirname)
      desktop-load-locked-desktop nil)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

I've checked the value of variable `desktop-restore-frames`, and Emacs reports "Its value is t", and its description says "When non-nil, save and restore the frame and window configuration".

I also use [perspective.el](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el), but I am not sure if it is related to the problem.

I wonder if the problem is caused by some conflict with other package/settings, and if possible, how do I detect and resolve such conflict.

Comment: If you don't get a reasonable explanation and solution here, consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: `desktop-save-mode` saves the window layout only on Emacs version 24.4 and higher, and not in terminal mode.

Answer (score 8):

In order for `desktop-read` (the function used to restore your desktop from a file) to restore the frameset that was saved in the desktop, it must call `desktop-restoring-frameset-p` (i.e., "should I restore the saved frameset?"), which in turn checks the function `display-graphic-p` (i.e., "is this a GUI or a TTY?").  This essentially means that, even though restoring the frameset *works* on the TTY (providing `desktop-restore-forces-onscreen` is `NIL`), it NEVER runs.  So we get the full desktop, but none of the frames.

I patched this up in my `.emacs` file by adding the following (to a function that runs when in a TTY):

```el
(setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)
(add-hook 'desktop-after-read-hook
 (lambda ()
   (frameset-restore
    desktop-saved-frameset
    :reuse-frames (eq desktop-restore-reuses-frames t)
    :cleanup-frames (not (eq desktop-restore-reuses-frames 'keep))
    :force-display desktop-restore-in-current-display
    :force-onscreen desktop-restore-forces-onscreen)))
```

This explicitly loads the saved frameset from `desktop-saved-frameset`, which `desktop` only defines while `desktop-read` is happening.

Comment: Wow, I've spent hours and hours trying to figure out why desktop-mode didn't work for this in my setup (in terminal mode) over a period of a few years, and after another 10 hours or so of over the last couple days, and now I finally found this answer! Thank you! It doesn't seem to work in Emacs client/server mode, though. Do you know what would be necessary to make that work?

Comment: It works like a charm! And works well with the new native tab-bar-mode! However the check for display-graphic-p appears to be a bad logic in the desktop package, and it avoid the load of frames as well as tabs-bars in terminal mode

Comment: @cyberbisson Thank you so much. This works great.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much: I couldn't suss this for the life of me!