# Restoring windows with Desktop when running Emacs inside a terminal?

Tags: frames, window-splitting, desktop

Maybe a silly question: I'm using desktop for saving Emacs' sessions. I've set

```
(setq desktop-restore-frames t)
(desktop-save-mode 0)
```

So windows and frames state is supposed to be saved, and I'm saving and reading desktop files manually.

When I run Emacs in its own X window, and I do `desktop-read` or `desktop-change-dir` everything is fine - frames, buffers and windows (including window splitting) are restored (for example, if I split a window with `C-x 2`, then save the desktop, this state is restored).

However, when I run Emacs either in a terminal emulator or in a virtual terminal only buffers are restored - window splitting is not shown, and although, when loading a desktop file I see a message like "Desktop: 2 frames, 5 buffers restored." in the minibuffer, and I see "F1" in the mode line, nothing happen when I do, for example `C-x 5 o` (that is, `other-frame`).

Is this how it is supposed to work or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs SE. `C-x 2` does not split the frame. It runs `split-window-below`. The analog for frames would be `C-x 5 2`, i.e., `make-frame-command`. To test whether multiple frames are present in an emacs on a text terminal you would have to type `C-x 5 o` for the command `other-frame`. Or maybe do `M-: (frame-list)` to get a list of current frames.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias. Perhaps I've used inaccurate terms. I edited my question to make it clearer. I did mean splitting a window.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with terminal Emacs 26.1 on Windows Subsystem 4 Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). As an add-on: Even with `Desktop: 2 frames, 0 buffers restored.` the answer to `M-: (remove terminal-frame (frame-list))` is `nil`, i.e., there exists only the `terminal-frame`.

Comment: Your question has already an answer [there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45829/2370).